# how to pass the arguments in R using opencpu

Tags: r, web-services, hadoop, opencpu

HI i am calling R program as a webservice using opencpu.when i call the program or passing the argument it shows timeout exception.This is my program.

```
test <- function(data)
{
setwd("/home/ec2-user")
args <- commandArgs(trailing = TRUE)
delhi <- read.delim("delhi.tsv", na.strings = "")
delhi$lnprice <- log(delhi$price)
delhi$furn.f = factor(delhi$furnished)
delhi <- delhi [(delhi$facing %in% c ("East", "West", "North", "South",  "South - East",  "South -West", "North - East", "North - West", NA)),]
delhi$fac.f = factor(delhi$facing)
delhi$age.f = factor(delhi$age)
delhi$own.f = factor (delhi$ownership)
delhi <- delhi[!table(delhi$locality)[delhi$locality]<20,]
delhi$loc.f = factor(delhi$locality)
delhi$address.f = factor(delhi$propertyaddress)
delhi <- delhi [!(delhi$locality %in% c ("Sector-1")),]
model <- lm(lnprice ~ bedrooms+ address.f,data = delhi)
address <- args[1]
result <- predict (model,address)
result
}
```

i am creaing a new package in r

```
package.skeleton(list = c("test"),environment = .GlobalEnv,code_files = character(),name="addresstest")
```

i am passing the argument by curl

```
http://52.25.248.111:5888/ocpu/library/addresstest/R/test/ -d "argument"
```

It is not working.i am new to r and opencpu . any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `commandArgs()` as you are not running a script. Try putting your  tsv file the package (via `inst`) because the webserver does not have persmission to read user home directories. And it looks like the `data` parameter is not actually used?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
curl http://52.25.248.111:5888/ocpu/library/addresstest/R/test/json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"data":"argumentValue"}'
```

It ends with this message :  `R call did not return within 90 seconds. Terminating process.`

Are you sure that function itself as described in test method is finishing in less then 90 sec? Also I don't see where do you use argument **data** at all in the method?